# HP Photosmart 3210 All-In-One nagging me - just want black and white

Tags: printer

The HP Photosmart 3210 All-In-One keeps nagging me about expired ink catridges. Went to store today and picked up one new Black ink catridge. The printer won't just let me use the black. So I put the old colors back in and tried to go to some kind of "b/w mode only" with no luck.

I'm a total newb to newer printers. How should I approach solving this? I don't want to buy color inks if I'm not going to use them. The printer was a gift. Not exactly what I really needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press 4 buttons at the same time... (With your right hand)
Color, Black, Reset, and OK.

Now press the "OFF" button wait for the printer to shut off and then turn it back "ON"

When you print, the printer will put the expired cartridge message. Press ">" ignore the warning, and Press "OK"

Go ahead and print all you want....

You will have to start the process over when you unplug power from your printer.....

Thanks to the Don in MI, who wrote about this, he deserves the credit for this find. HP will not tell us how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do - Welcome to the world of printer DRM.

The best thing you can do is go to your local ink supplier and buy a compatible cartridge at a fraction of the price along with a chip resetter.

Unlike with Epsons, the only HP chip resetters I have seen, only work with compatible inks.

You can then use as much Black as you want and just use the resetter whenever you get a warning.

Comment: Thanks Wil. I just broke down and paid $40 for more color inks. At some point my time more valuable then running around hacking things. But I will look into this chip resetter stuff.